# crudbooster, How to change storage path in laravel to public?

Tags: laravel, upload, storage, public

I use crudbooster admin generator in laravel 5.4, if I upload a file from a form, it will be stored in own storage directory. Then I should create a symlink to that storage path in public path.

I can't use creating symlinks on my system because of the limitation. How can I upload files directly to public/uploads instead of storage/app/uploads?

Comment: when I use crudbooster, it stores image file to storage/app/uploads/06-2017/image.png and insert to databse as uploads/06-2017/image.png  I want to change this situations.

Comment: Can you please share the code you are using in your controller when you upload the form data? I'm not familiar with crudbooster, but after looking at documentation it looks as if it's built on top of laravel. When uploading, it's most likely using laravels Storage facade.

Comment: sorry, I can not find crudbooster controller because, my controller and crudbooster controller are different.

Comment: Could you send a picture of your config directory? I'd like to see the config file names so I can find out know what options crudbooster is giving your application.

Comment: project folder :  hizliresim.com/aGjmO7       and conf: https://hizliresim.com/3qN0RO

Comment: Can you post the content of lfm.php

Comment: lfm file : https://ufile.io/qpz4w

Comment: I edited my answer, sorry I couldn't be of more help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I honestly have no clue. Best I can do is point you in the right direction. Crudbooster depends on a package called UniShard/laravel-filemanager. I was looking through the config file for this package and it is similar to the lfm.php in your config folder except there are more options. Perhaps you could use one of these additional options such as `base_directory`. Not sure how this will work out and it could just be poorly coded.

### Original Answer:

You need to create a new disk.

In config\filesystems.php, add this.

```
'disks' => [
    'uploads' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => public_path() . '/uploads'
    ],
],
```

Now, when you want to use the storage facade you can just do this:

```
Storage::disk('uploads');
```

An example usage:

```
Storage::disk('uploads')->put('filename', $file_content);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -2):

we can change it in

vendor/crocodicstudio/crudbooster/src/controllers/cbcontroller.php line: 1010